# How do I print a receipt on android using Python?

Tags: python, android, printing, kivy

I have written a simple cash register app (for android) using Kivy for my friend who's opening up a shop. I was wondering if anyone knows how to print an actual receipt using Python?

I know how to create the receipt and I can find out how to make it into a pdf or a textfile but I can't seem to find a way to send it to a printer once a button is pressed.
Is it something that can be done easily?

I've done a google search but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: I was going to ask the same but I am trying Beeware+Toga.

Comment: I found this useful https://gist.github.com/tito/7432757
I just had to use the java module from Chaquopy, but kivy should have an android module, so it would be slightly different. 
For the printer languge this can be useful https://github.com/BoboTiG/thermalprinter

For now I can print ascii text and connect to the printer by name. I will look now for the fancy formatting and so on.